# How can I stop form event listener to trigger for previous click?

Tags: javascript, loops, event-listener

A loop runs through a json and generates **change** buttons and inserts them into a div. Each button has an event listener attached to it. When the button **change** is clicked a form appears below. This form will send the data to a database when I click save.
**The problem**: If I click on multiple **change** buttons and then on the **save** button the form will send data corresponding to all the previous clicks not only the last one.

```
for(let i=0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) {
    const pagetype = json[i]['pagetype'];

    var d1 = document.getElementById('dispDiv');
    d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div><p><button id="change">Change</button>');

    const change = document.getElementById('change');
    change.addEventListener("click", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            saveChanges(pagetype);
     });
}

function saveChanges(pagetype) {
    const formDiv = document.getElementById('divForm');
    const changeForm = document.getElementById('changeForm');
    formDiv.style.display = 'block';

    changeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const changeFormObj = new FormData(changeForm);
        changeFormObj.append('pageType', pageType);

        saveChangesAsy(changeFormObj);
    });

    async function saveChangesAsy(formObj) {

    //some code to comunicate with the database

    }
}
```

Like I said the problem occurs when I click on multiple **change** buttons and then on **SAVE** button. It triggers the 'submit' event listeners for all the Form elements corresponding to the previous **change** buttons, not only the last one.